# Is it expected to see transition from laminar to turbulent BL at low Reynolds numbers?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, boundary-layer, laminar-flow

I have used XFOIL to do the following analysis:

- NACA0018 airfoil.
- Reynolds number $2\times 10^4$ (low Reynolds number).
- Critical Amplification factor, $N_\mathrm{crit} = 3.54$ (corresponding to a freestream turbulence level of 0.7%). I have used the formula from [this thread](https://www.cfd-online.com/Forums/main/120467-aerofoil-problem.html#post438957).

When I run the analysis at $\alpha = 5^\circ$, I get the following results:

[image]

However, I am confused as I don't understand how to interpret the results:

- Is the plateau in pressure coefficient an indication of transition from laminar-to-turbulent boundary layer? if so, I feel it's wrong since the freestream Reynolds number is very low ($2\times 10^4)$ and I do not expect transition at such low Re numbers (I can't find the source, but I read somwhere that the transition from laminar-to-turbulent is expected for $Re \geq 7\times 10^4$ ).
- 

Answer (score 1):

> Is the plateau in pressure coefficient an indication of transition from laminar-to-turbulent boundary layer?

Yes. The plateau is actually the separation bubble and transition happens at the rear end of it, shortly before the steep pressure increase made possible by the now turbulent boundary layer. Check the Xtr output of XFOIL! This you will get for example by plotting the boundary layer details, or when writing a sweep of points to a file.

> I read somwhere that the transition from laminar-to-turbulent is expected for ≥7×10⁴

That depends on the history of the boundary layer and the local pressure gradient. See it this way: A positive pressure gradient means that the flow is decelerated. The initially small disturbances (flow speeds orthogonal to the actual direction of flow) will grow relatively larger when the speed in the direction of flow sinks. This allows transition already at Re well below 10⁵, and with your very low Ncrit even at 10⁴. Normally, Ncrit should be around 9.

Besides, your Reynolds number is very low, even for XFOIL. Did you have a chance to compare them with actual measurements?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The reason I have a doubt about the LSB is the following paper (See figure 2): ` J. Winslow, H. Otsuka, B. Govindarajan, and I. Chopra, “Basic understanding of airfoil characteristics at low Reynolds numbers (104–105),” J. Aircr., vol. 55, no. 3, pp. 1050–1061, 2018.`